# go-mssql set connection timeout

Tags: sql-server, go

I'm having issues setting the timeout in go-mssqldb

This is my current connection string:

```
sqlserver://user:password@server?timeout=1m30s
```

I can connect just fine, run queries etc. but I keep timing out at the default value of 30 seconds.
I'm referencing the documentation [here](https://github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb).

What am I missing?

```
import (
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb"
)

func main(){
    db, err := sql.Open("mssql", "sqlserver://user:password@server?timeout=1m30s")
    if err != nil{
        panic(err)
    }

    _, err = db.Exec("run query that takes longer than 30 seconds")
    if err != nil{
         panic(err)
    }
    // panic at 30 seconds...
    // panic: read tcp {my ip}->{server ip}: i/o timeout

}
```

Comment: there's two different time outs in sql server, and it looks like the one you're setting is the "connection timeout" (how long it'll wait to make a connection). does the api you use refer anywhere to a "command" or "query" timeout? (I can see a read and write timeout, but they say they deafult to 0 which I'd assume is unlimited)

Comment: The timeout depends on the connection time taking to connect to sql-server. It does not seems like query execution time out. Did you check it by removing the timeout.

Comment: @TZHX good call. So the default for readTimeout and writeTimout is 0 which should be unlimited. I just tried `sqlserver://user:password@server?readTimeout=1m30s` and am still getting timed-out at 30 seconds

Comment: Not sure why you are referencing docs for a different project.  According to the docs here: https://github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb it looks like you might want to add `connection+timeout=90` to you connection string.

Comment: ah shame. I got confused in my documentation googling. Thank you for setting me straight. `connection+timeout=#` worked. I initially tried `connection+timeout=0` which timed out immediately contrary to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I was referencing the wrong documentation initially. To format the url see the following:

```
"sqlserver://user:password@server?connection+timeout=90"
```

Comment: I changed the parameter for `?dial+timeout=90`